# Manage records in datatable

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable

I have datatable having data district name, progress percentage and count.

```
District      Progress %      Count

Amritsar      100            2
Amritsar      89             3
Amritsar       0             1
Amritsar       24            5
Barnala        70            2
Barnala        55            3
Mohali         15            5
Mohali         100           3
Mohali         30            5
```

and so on....

And I want to display the data in datatable having count of records comes under particular progress % Range

```
District     0%      1-25%      26-50%    51-75%     76-99%      100%

Amritsar     1        5          0          0          3          2
Barnala      0        0          0          5          0          0
Mohali       0        5          5          0          0          3
```

ans so on...

Please give an idea how to do this. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SQL you can do it with *conditional aggregation*:

```sql
SELECT District,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress = 0 THEN 1 END) AS '0%',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN 1 END) AS '1-25%',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress BETWEEN 26 AND 50 THEN 1 END) AS '26-50%',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress BETWEEN 51 AND 75 THEN 1 END) AS '51-75%',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress BETWEEN 76 AND 99 THEN 1 END) AS '76-99%',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Progress = 100 THEN 1 END) AS '100%'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY District
```

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos. My problem is solved by using this SQL query.